# "Page Not Found/404 handler” to Swift Express Server

Tags: linux, swift, web, swift2, swiftexpress

I’m writing the simplest server via [Swift Express](https://github.com/crossroadlabs/Express)

And I want to add custom handler for “url not found” so that if user write “/notFoundUrl” he will see something like that:   “Url “notFoundUrl” not found, please go to home page”.

I’ve added:

```
app.get("/:notFoundUrl+") { (request:Request<AnyContent>)->Action<AnyContent> in
   print(request.params["notFoundUrl"])
   return Action<AnyContent>.render("index", context: ["hello": "Page Not Found: " + request.params["notFoundUrl"]!])
}
```

But it’s not appropriate becouse:

- Order does matter.
- I can’t return 404 error.

So how to add custom “Page Not Found/404 handler” to [Swift Express Server](https://github.com/crossroadlabs/Express)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It much simpler than you are trying to do it.

```
/// Custom page not found error handler
app.errorHandler.register { (e:ExpressError) in
    switch e {
    case .PageNotFound(let path):
        return Action<AnyContent>.render("404", context: ["path": path], status: .NotFound)
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

The full do can be found here: https://github.com/crossroadlabs/Express/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/errorhandling.md